# Direct products of infinite groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

By an argument which is not entirely trivial we know that if $G,H$ are finite groups and $G \times G \cong H \times H$, then $G \cong H$. I was wondering if this result holds if $G, H$ are infinite, and if not, then what a counterexample is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the wikipedia entry [Rank of an abelian group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_of_an_abelian_group) there are rank 2 abelian groups 
$A=A_{m,n}$ and $B=B_{m,n}$ ($m,n\in\mathbb{N}$) such that $A^n$ is isomorphic to $B^n$ if and only if $m$ divides $n$. If this is so, then of course taking $m=n=2$ gives a counterexample. This result appears to be due to A.L.S. Corner who has various striking results that show that non-finitely generated abelian groups behave very strangely.

Comment: I've found the paper where this result appears: 
Corner, A. L. S.
On endomorphism rings of primary abelian groups.
Quart. J. Math. Oxford Ser. (2) 20 1969 277–296.